# Hadoop Framework to simulate a cluster locally

Tags: hadoop

Is there any Hadoop framework wherein I can simulate a full cluster locally on a Linux or Windows Machine? The DFS could replicate the data locally and the Compute layer would do parallel execution?
Is there any such or similar framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Hadoop on one or more Virtual machines. E.g. Cloudera offers a [downloadable VM](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera%27s+Hadoop+Demo+VM) pre-installed with its Hadoop distro

Answer (score 1):

[Reference :](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12449832/rumen.pdf) Rumen is a data extraction and analysis tool built for MapReduce. Rumen mines JobHistory logs to extract meaningful data and stores it in an easily-parsed format. Rumen performs statistical analysis of the information mined from JobHistory logs which could by other tools carrying out tasks like simulation, emulation and benchmarking. Rumen forms the
foundation for GridMix (v3) and Mumak.

[Reference :](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/08/what%E2%80%99s-new-in-apache-hadoop-0-21/) Other new contrib modules include Rumen (MAPREDUCE-751) and Mumak (MAPREDUCE-728), tools for modelling MapReduce. The two are designed to work together: Rumen extracts job data from historical logs, which Mumak then uses to simulate MapReduce applications and clusters on a cluster. Gridmix3 is also designed to work with Rumen traces. The job history log analyzer is another tool that gives information about MapReduce cluster utilization (HDFS-459).

Sample [Rumen](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/src/test/tools/data/rumen/) data is in SVN. FYI, Rumen and Mumak are contrib modules and there is not much documentation available. Here is a nice article on [GridMix](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/posts/2010/04/gridmix3_emulating_production/).